# how to use bootstrap modal with lots of images

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am building a gallery with bootstrap that contains about a hundred images. 
Is there an efficient way to use the modal instead of writing it for each image separately?

Answer (score 0):

Best to use bootstrap lightbox plugin

http://ashleydw.github.io/lightbox/#image-gallery

Use it like this

```
<a href="someurl" data-toggle="lightbox">Launch modal</a>
```